# SAMBA shares don't work with short server name

Tags: active-directory, samba, internal-dns, file-sharing

I have a legacy SAMBA server to share files.
But I can't mount windows disk with short name:

```
net view \\dades.company.es   -> That work
net view \\dades                -> That don't work
net view \\192.168.1.3          -> That work

C:\>nslookup dades   ->> *** UnKnown no encuentra dades: Non-existent domain

C:\>nslookup dades.company.es

Nombre:  dades.company.es
Address:  192.168.1.3
```

Ipconfig now is:

```
C:\> ipconfig /all

Configuración IP de Windows

   Nombre de host. . . . . . . . . : DESK-HP
   Sufijo DNS principal  . . . . . : INTERNAL
   Tipo de nodo. . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Enrutamiento IP habilitado. . . : no
   Proxy WINS habilitado . . . . . : no
   Lista de búsqueda de sufijos DNS: INTERNAL

Adaptador de Ethernet Conexión de área local:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.121(Preferido)
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concesión obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : miércoles, 16 de diciembre de 2020 18:51:57
   La concesión expira . . . . . . . . . . . : viernes, 18 de diciembre de 2020 20:52:06
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado
```

So, I get an old printout. Take note:

- Lista de busqueda de sufijos DNS    ->   DNS suffix Search List
- Sufijo DNS especifico para la conexion   ->  Connection-Specific DNS suffix

Take a look on **company.es**, was present on the past

I suppose I should fix:  "DNS suffix Search List"

```
Configuracion IP de Windows

   Nombre de host. . . . . . . . . : DESK-HP
   Sufijo DNS principal  . . . . . : INTERNAL
   Tipo de nodo. . . . . . . . . . : h¡brido
   Enrutamiento IP habilitado. . . : no
   Proxy WINS habilitado . . . . . : no
   Lista de b£squeda de sufijos DNS: INTERNAL
                                       company.es

Adaptador de Ethernet Conexi¢n de  rea local:

   Sufijo DNS espec¡fico para la conexi¢n. . : company.es
   Descripci¢n . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Direcci¢n f¡sica. . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : s¡
   Configuraci¢n autom tica habilitada . . . : s¡
   Direcci¢n IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.121(Preferido) 
   M scara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concesi¢n obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : mi‚rcoles, 15 de abril de 2020 2:53:24
   La concesi¢n expira . . . . . . . . . . . : mi‚rcoles, 29 de abril de 2020 19:33:16
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
                                       80.58.0.33
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado
```

So the question is where can configure ON SAMBA(not each windows machine), to include "DNS suffix Search"?

Answer (score 2):

*Please edit your question adding more details, expecially OSes versions, network topology and network services versions.*

DNS suffix search cannot be set in the SAMBA `smb.conf` file since the SMB protocol cannot be used to set this parameter on client side.
Since your clients have their IP addresses dynamically assigned by a DHCP server, you should configure the DNS suffix in the DHCP server settings, in order to automatically push it to your clients.

If your DHCP server is implemented with the `dhcpd` daemon running on a Linux server, you have to add the following option in `dhcpd.conf` file: `option domain-name "company.es";`

In case your DHCP server is the Windows Server built-in one, add the `015 DNS Domain Name` option to your pool.

**NOTE**
Please be careful about terminology. Remember that the term "Server" is commonly used to refer to both a centralized machine that executes various services used by clients in the network and a single piece of software that implements a network service (SAMBA is a server, APACHE is a server, etc.)

Comment: Hi. Very clear answer. Really DHCP server (192.168.1.1) was changed between two printouts, now is a FORTINET firewall. I checked this but can`t find any parameter like "domain name" on GUI.

Comment: Don't be lazy... https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.2.1/cli-reference/59620/system-dhcp-server